# Cisco Umbrella is blocking my Node.js App in Heroku website?

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, cisco, umbrella

I'm a beginner in Node.JS and Mongoose. I have created a small Node.JS app. I have pushed the code into Github and Heroku server. After I have deployed the code into the Heroku server. I have checked my website online. It's working fine. I  have used and done some operations in online itself. It has been worked fine, very well.

After One hour I hit my link in google. It's showing **This site is blocked due to a security threat.**   **This site is blocked due to a security threat that was discovered by the Cisco Umbrella security researchers.** .Why? what is the reason? what happened? what are the steps should I follow. Can anyone help me to work on my app online?

It will really helpful for me. any kind of help would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get no access to more details?

Comment: yes. I have searched on google but I didn't get an appropriate solution. If anything suggests to me.

Answer (score 2):

Cisco Umbrella will block sites it deems to be a Security Threat to help protect people accessing these sites.  This is normally because the site has been associated with one of three activities: malware, phishing, or command and control. If the domain is new then Cisco Umbrella has an option to block new domains for a period of time to protect users against temporary malicious domains.

This protection is achieved when using Cisco Umbrella as a DNS resolvee.  This is either done using a client on your device or as a network configuration.

If your certain the domain is safe, you can whitelistthe dmain via the Umbrella Dashboard, if available.  Alternativly use another DNS resolver services such as Google which offers no protection or filtering.